# apply function to specific columns of data frame

Tags: r

I have a big data frame with n number of columns , now i am trying to do sum of rows of all clumns which start with "col" and exclude the columns which ends with "max".

i am getting a error

```
data <- data.frame(newid= c(212,132,354,222,263,235,233,263,106,135,144),
                   col1= c(1,2,2,1,4,3,2,4,0,5,0),
                   col2= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col3= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col4= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col_max= c("NM","mn","PA","OH","KL","AB","OT","HA","AM","LA","GA"))


df1 <- df %>% summarise(across(starts_with("col_") &  names(df) != ends_with("_max"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 <- data %>% summarise(across(starts_with("col") &  !ends_with("_max"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Result:

```
> df1 <- data %>% summarise(across(starts_with("col") &  !ends_with("_max"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
> df1
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   24   21   21   21
```

I just modified `names(data) != ends_with("_max")` to `!ends_with("_max")`.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R` one option would be

```
colSums(x = data[, grepl(pattern = "^col+\\d",  
                         x = colnames(x = data))])
```

From the column names of `data` grab any columns starting with `col` followed by a digit. Subset `data` accordingly and calculate column sums. Include `na.rm = TRUE` as argument of `colSums()` if necessary.
I assume `& !grepl(pattern = "_max$",  x = colnames(x = data))` is not needed.

If you are looking for an `apply()` solution:

```
apply(X = data[, grepl(pattern = "^col+\\d",  
                       x = colnames(x = data))], 
      MARGIN = 2, 
      FUN = sum)
```